# C# Lambda .Contains() on multiple properties

Tags: c#, search, lambda, contains

We are using the following to generate a search query (using NHibernate).

```
GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH)).ToList();
```

Is it possible to do a search (Contains) for multiple properties, something like ...

```
    GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        && x => x.Firstname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        && x => x.Lastname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH)).ToList();
```

Using C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        && x.Firstname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        && x.Lastname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH)).ToList();
```

I'd imagine you'd want to do a search on OR though:

```
GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        || x.Firstname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
        || x.Lastname.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Nick ... you're right about OR. Was just the semantics I was interested in. Can't believe it was so easy ... Answer +1

Comment: @Hugusta: Accept an answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: yes, I intend to. I couldn't before because of the time-limit and then got distracted. Right now, clicking the button has my full attention! Watch this .....

Answer (score 0):

Try [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/).

It will allow the following syntax:

```
var result = GetAll().Search("search", 
                             x => x.Username, 
                             x => x.Firstname, 
                             x => x.Lastname)
                     .ToList();
```

When used with sql, this will produce something like the following:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
       [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
       [Extent1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname], 
       [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname]
FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Username] LIKE N'%search%') 
   OR ([Extent1].[Firstname] LIKE N'%search%') 
   OR ([Extent1].[Lastname] LIKE N'%search%')
```

... meaning all the work is done at the data source, and not in memory

For the source code, take a look at the github page:

https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions